# Search in HTML file - Swift

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview

My app has the ability to search in HTML files for strings like 'Art. 1'. I do this using a Javascript search script. This works great with some HTML's where Art. 1 is just written in plain text, but now I need to get it to work when that's not the case. An example:

```
<a>Art.</a> <a href="stackoverflow.com"> 2</a>
```

When you search for Art. 1, it obviously doesn't work. What I would need is something that represents any text between the Art. and the 2, I believe. How would I be able to accomplish this in JavaScript?

Thanks for your help, as I have no clue on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a regular expression that can either strip out the HTML tags, or return only the non-HTML part. Regular Expressions are very powerful patterns that match text in a string. You can find information here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Comment: Indeed, it is a regular expression that I need! I have heard of this before but totally forgot about it. Thanks a lot!